# Apache Cordova 2.0 show infinite input text when load the web page

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have follow [this guideline](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS) to embed a Cordova web application in my iOs app:

```
CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
viewController.wwwFolderName = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"/data/volumes/%@",
                                self.book.code];
viewController.startPage = @"index.html";//@"gallery.html";
viewController.useSplashScreen = NO;
viewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

all works good but when the CDVViewController load the html page (the test index.html proposed on the howto) the app show infinite input text box, with different strings

[image]

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved:
In the Phonegap library every OS have own cordova-2.0.0.js, I was loading the Android version :)